# Why is PDFBox giving unexpected error after adding to Libraries and Modules in IntelliJ Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-17

I am getting the following error:

```
    /Users/username/IdeaProjects/WrestlingProject/src/DataScraper.java:22:41
    java: cannot access org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead
      class file for org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead not found
```

When running the following code segment:

```
    public class DataScraper{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                File folderFile = new File("pdf");

                File pdfFile = folderFile.listFiles()[0];

                PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(pdfFile);
                PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();

                String text = stripper.getText(document);
                System.out.println("Text in the PDF: " + text);
                document.close();



            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The PDFBox jar was applied in the Project Structure libraries tab.
My goal is to turn a pdf file into a raw stream of text.

Why is the error showing up, and how do I fix it?

I tried running it, and tried several pdf paths, but I believe the path is correct.

Comment: The error is a class error, not an inability to locate a pdf file.

Comment: the code shown only have like 21 lines including the whitespaces but the error says line 22.. so... did you strip some parts?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the Project Structure Libraries tab? What's the jar's file name?